# JOIN with second select result

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've two tables: 
perfil (profile) and user

On perfil I have the column user_id that means the specified user.

I am trying to take with user.user (that means kevinkouketsu for example) the user.id to use on perfil.user_id

```
SELECT perfil.*, userId.*, r.Nome as cityName, userId.id as userId 
FROM perfil 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM user WHERE user='SOMEVALUE') as userId ON perfil.user_id=userId.id 
LEFT JOIN municipio AS r ON perfil.city=r.Codigo
```

I made this code and results everything on perfil table and alias userId results NULL.

Results example:

```
array (size=20)   
 'id' => null  
 'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)  
 'conjuge' => string 'Alice Elias Patrício' (length=21)  
 'conjuge_aniver' => string '2018-02-24 20:49:10' (length=19)  
 'state' => string 'SC' (length=2)  
 'city' => string '4217709' (length=7)  
 'perfil_img' => string '' (length=0)  
 'user' => null  
 'senha' => null    
 'email' => null  
 'nome' => null  
 'access' => null  
 'type' => null  
 'empresa_id' => null
 'rede_id' => null  
 'birthday' => null  
 'created' => null  
 'phone' => null  
 'cityName' => string 'Sombrio' (length=7)  
 'userId' => null<
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question but I think you mean this: `SELECT perfil.*, user.*, r.Nome as cityName FROM perfil LEFT JOIN user ON perfil.user_id=user.id LEFT JOIN municipio AS r ON perfil.city=r.Codigo` (assuming the primary key on `user` is `id`)

Comment: Two things:  `id` its a integer and  `user` its a string to url, example: 127.0.0.1/profile/kevin you know what I mean? So... I need to take this 
  `kevin` and search  `'id` to get perfil table. I need another select like example, i guess

Comment: I don't understand. You are selecting all perfils, and for the user 'SOMEVALUE' you are also selecting the user data (whereas for all other perfils you don't and leave this data empty). And the question is?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT perfil.*, user.*, r.Nome as cityName, user.id as userId 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN perfil ON perfil.user_id=user.id 
LEFT JOIN municipio AS r ON perfil.city=r.Codigo
WHERE user.user='SOMEVALUE'
```

Comment: Worked in some case. When perfil table dont have `user_id` that is not configured a custom profile and have just the simple profile, return null.

Comment: Worked with new query. Thanks!

Comment: @shepher if it worked please don't forget to upvote this answer :)